# Can I kill apt.system.daily to fix the apt install command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, pid

When I try to install anything (Ubuntu 16.04) with apt or apt-get I get this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

This is the output of `ps aux | grep apt`:

```
root     23906  0.0  0.0   4504   784 ?        Ss   Feb20   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
root     23912  0.0  0.0   4504  1640 ?        S    Feb20   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install
```

But these are the sub processes:

```
root     23906  0.0  0.0   4504   784 ?        Ss   Feb20   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily install
root     23912  0.0  0.0   4504  1640 ?        S    Feb20   0:00  \_ /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held install
root     23943  0.1  3.7 140052 77424 ?        S    Feb20  56:54      \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
root     23948  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Feb20   0:00          \_ [dpkg-deb] <defunct>
root     23965  0.0  2.9 140632 59508 ?        S    Feb20  31:44          \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
root     24051  0.0  0.2  19196  4632 pts/0    Ss+  Feb20   0:00              \_ /usr/bin/dpkg --status-fd 10 --configure redis-server:amd64 linux-modules-4.4.0-1102-aws:amd64 linux-image-4.4.0-1102-aws:amd64 linux-image-aws:amd64 linux-a
root     24052  0.0  0.0   4504  1660 pts/0    S+   Feb20   0:00                  \_ /bin/sh /var/lib/dpkg/info/redis-server.postinst configure
root     24094  0.0  0.0   4504  1696 pts/0    S+   Feb20   0:00                      \_ /bin/sh /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d redis-server start
root     24138  0.0  0.0  24888  1340 pts/0    S+   Feb20   0:11                          \_ systemctl start redis-server.service
```

I believe that the PIDs from ps aux | grep apt are holding my apt install command but I don't want to kill the redis-server PID in the subprocesses and all the other PIDs eventhough systemctl status says that both redis and redis server state is deactivating (stop-post). And last time someone tried to install anything was redis-server

Comment: shorzly yes, i do ot some times

Comment: Thisi is a production server, what would happen to the redis-server and why is it connected with the daily install?

Comment: `root     23948  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Feb20   0:00          \_ [dpkg-deb] <defunct>` dpkg is broken sofat kill the processes and restart via `apt install -f` or `dpkg-reconfigure -a`

Answer (score 6):

Those are unattended upgrades, which acquire a different lock than the usual `apt-get`.

The simple way to install after the unattended upgrades pass is by waiting its lock to finish with `flock`. `flock` will wait until the lock is released and then it will execute sequentially `update`, `upgrade` and `install`.

```
 flock /var/lib/apt/daily_lock \
  apt-get -y update \
  && apt-get -y upgrade \
  && apt-get -y install \
    zip \
    unzip
```

References:

- [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)
- [flock](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)
- [Another's man take](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Handling-the-apt-lock-on-ubuntu-server-installations/)

Answer (score 3):

1:
Check apt services installed with:
systemctl list-units | grep apt

Disable the running apt services:
systemctl disable apt*.
e.g.
sudo systemctl disable apt-daily.service

**Refer** a very clean process at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038923/do-i-really-need-apt-daily-service-and-apt-daily-upgrade-service

2:
You might also want to set to zero or false some of the config values of apt.conf files at
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic

Refer:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167314/disable-automatic-updates-ubuntu-18-04

You most likely will be good with #1 above.

Hope this helps

Thanks